# Show Array Value in JavaDocs

Tags: java, arrays, int, javadoc

Lets say I have got such code:

```
private static final int[] ARRAY = {5, 10, 15};

/**
 * ????
 */
public void doSomething()
{}
```

I am wondering, if is there any way to put value of the ARRAY into documentation of `doSomething()` method.
I can see that `@value #ARRAY` isn't working at all for arrays :(
`@link #ARRAY` is not showing me the value.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why won't you use Enum instead of array?

Comment: Because when i try to make enum where values are numbers, it gives me "Unexpected token" error

Comment: This happens because Java identifier (name of variable, method or class) cannot start with a digit. You can however store a numeric value, as a property of each enum's instance. See `enum Planet` example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Well yes, but in my case nothing(like a planet) hides behind the number. Lets say i would like to store in ARRAY PI numbers up to 10, it would be nice to see their values in JavaDocs. You see storing them as enum and creating new name for each one doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Could you please tell us what's your actuall array and method? Maybe there's another approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `@value` only works for constants, i.e. `static final` values. The array *contents* are not constants, only the array *object* itself is. You can change the values at any time. So it doesn't make sense, technically, to show the values. The array object itself can't be shown at Javadoc creation time in any useful way, like any other object (except `String`s).

Comment: So there is no way to do what i would like to? Array with always constant values that could be seen in Docs

Comment: You could define constants and use them as array values. But an array can't be made immutable.